# can't fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'jQuery' of undefined on line 562

Tags: jquery, methods, call, undefined, typeerror

var nn=oTable.jQuery('input:checked').serialize() keeps throwing error even when using noConflict. on jsfiddle it shows that my code is corect but still the problem persists.i've searched enough in google but with no luck.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="hu" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="hu"/>    
    <meta http-equiv="ImageToolbar" content="False" />
    <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="True" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../res/x5engine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.md5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css" media="screen" />
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "media/css/demo_table_jui.css";
            @import "jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";
            @import "extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css";
        </style>
  <title>Adminisztráció</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="imNavBar">
            <a href="kereso.php">Kereső</a>
<a href="munka.php">Munka</a>
<a href="ujd.php">Újdonságok</a>
<a href="pass.php">Jelszó</a>
<span>
    <a href="login.php?logout">Kilépés</a>
</span>     </div>

<div id='imAdminPage'>
    <div id='imBody'>
        <div class='imSectionTitle'>Kereső</div>
        <div class='imContent' style='width:auto;margin-left: auto ;margin-right: auto ;text-align: center;'>

<form name='osszes' id='osszes' method='post' action='mentes.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<table class='display' id='table_id' border='0' style='width: 100%;' align='center'>
<thead>
<tr class='vami'>
<th>ID:</th>
<td>Sezonier, Operator la bandă, Industria auto, IT</td>
<td>Akarhol</td>
<td><span><input class='codes' type='checkbox' id='31' name='kodok[]' value='31' />
&nbsp;Lementeni</span>
</td>
<td>
<a target='_blank' href='mentes2.php?kod=31'>Megnéz</a>
</td>  
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id='inputok'></div>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><script>
var oTable,oTable2,oTable3;
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(':checkbox').live('click',function(){
    var nn=oTable.jQuery('input:checked').serialize()
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'jQuery' of undefined
    ;var n=nn.length;
    if (n!='0'){
        $('#imObjectForm').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    else {
        $('#imObjectForm').attr('disabled',true);
        }
});    
    jQuery('#osszes').submit(function(){
        $("input:hidden").remove();
        var fields = oTable.$('input').serializeArray();
        $.each(fields, function(i, field){
            $('<input type="hidden" id="imSpProt" name="imSpProt[]" value="' + field.value + '" />').appendTo('#inputok');
            });
    });
Table = jQuery('#table_id').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": '400px',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bSort": false,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sDom": '<"H"lfrT>t<"F"ip>',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends":    "text",
                    "sButtonText": "<input id='imObjectForm' name='submit' type='submit' value='Kiválasztottak lementése' disabled='disabled' />"
                }
            ]
        },
       "oLanguage":  {
    "sProcessing":   "Feldolgozás...",
    "sLengthMenu":   "_MENU_ találat oldalanként",
    "sZeroRecords":  "Nincs a keresésnek megfelelő találat",
    "sInfo":         "Találatok: _START_ - _END_ Összesen: _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty":    "Nulla találat",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(_MAX_ összes rekord közül szűrve)",
    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
    "sSearch":       "Keresés:",
    "sUrl":          "",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Első",
        "sPrevious": "Előző",
        "sNext":     "Következő",
        "sLast":     "Utolsó"
    }
}
    });
    oTable2 = jQuery('#kepek').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": '500px',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bSort": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
       "oLanguage":  {
    "sProcessing":   "Feldolgozás...",
    "sLengthMenu":   "_MENU_ találat oldalanként",
    "sZeroRecords":  "Nincs a keresésnek megfelelő találat",
    "sInfo":         "Találatok: _START_ - _END_ Összesen: _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty":    "Nulla találat",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(_MAX_ összes rekord közül szűrve)",
    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
    "sSearch":       "Keresés:",
    "sUrl":          "",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Első",
        "sPrevious": "Előző",
        "sNext":     "Következő",
        "sLast":     "Utolsó"
    }
}
    });
    oTable3 = jQuery('#adatok').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": '473px',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bSort": false,
       "oLanguage":  {
    "sProcessing":   "Feldolgozás...",
    "sLengthMenu":   "_MENU_ találat oldalanként",
    "sZeroRecords":  "Nincs a keresésnek megfelelő találat",
    "sInfo":         "Találatok: _START_ - _END_ Összesen: _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty":    "Nulla találat",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(_MAX_ összes rekord közül szűrve)",
    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
    "sSearch":       "Keresés:",
    "sUrl":          "",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Első",
        "sPrevious": "Előző",
        "sNext":     "Következő",
        "sLast":     "Utolsó"
    }
}
    });
    oTable4 = jQuery('#adatok2').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": '350px',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,        
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bSort": false,
       "oLanguage":  {
    "sProcessing":   "Feldolgozás...",
    "sLengthMenu":   "_MENU_ találat oldalanként",
    "sZeroRecords":  "Nincs a keresésnek megfelelő találat",
    "sInfo":         "Találatok: _START_ - _END_ Összesen: _TOTAL_",
    "sInfoEmpty":    "Nulla találat",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(_MAX_ összes rekord közül szűrve)",
    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
    "sSearch":       "Keresés:",
    "sUrl":          "",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Első",
        "sPrevious": "Előző",
        "sNext":     "Következő",
        "sLast":     "Utolsó"
    }
}
    });
jQuery('form#urlapocska').submit(function(){
    $(".error").hide();
    var hasError = false;
    var pasw = $("#regipass").val();
    var passwordVal2 = $.md5(pasw);
    var checkVal2 = $("#jelszo").val();
    var passwordVal = $("#ujpass").val();
    var checkVal = $("#ujpass2").val();
    if (passwordVal2 === '') {
        $("#egyes").after('<span class="error">Nem írtad be a régi jelszót.</span>');hasError = true;
        }
    else if (passwordVal2 != checkVal2 ) {
        $("#egyes").after('<span class="error">Nem talál a régi jelszó.</span>');
        hasError = true;
        }
    if (passwordVal === '') {
        $("#kettes").after('<span class="error">Nem írtál jelszót.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if (checkVal === '') {
        $("#harmas").after('<span class="error">Jelszó megismétlése szükséges.</span>');
        hasError = true;
        }
    else if (passwordVal != checkVal){
        $("#harmas").after('<span class="error">A jelszók nem találnak.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }
    if(hasError === true) {
        return false;
        }
});    
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from your code you are attempting to find the `input:checked` elements within the `oTable` element. If that is the case, try this:

```
var nn = jQuery('input:checked', oTable).serialize()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's working now.but the serialize isn't working anymore like it should.it only selects those input's checked that are visible in DataTables oTable.

Comment: Glad this helped. Try opening another question for that problem - remember to only include the relevant code though, not a massive dump of everything :)

Comment: ok i will open another question for that and i will try not to dump everything in it ;)